# Solve for the value $X$ and $Y$ using the equations $X+Y=10$ and $3.1X+2.5Y= 26.16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem that wants me to calculate the number of pennies in a container. It comes from a chemistry context, so the numbers may not be exact in the mathematical sense.

There are two types of pennies in the container, pre-1982 pennies (X), and post-1982 pennies (Y).

The total number of pennies is $10$ and the total weight of the pennies is $26.16 \textrm{ g}$. The pre-1982 pennies (X) mass is $3.1\textrm{ g}$ each and the post-1982 pennies (Y) mass is $2.5\textrm{ g}$.

Equation 1 is $$3.1X+2.5Y= 26.16$$
Equation 2 is $$X+Y=10$$

I found the answer after rounding is $X=2$ and $Y=8$ but I could not find the math on how to get that answer.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain it to me.

Thanks.

Comment: If $X+Y=10$ then $Y=10-X$, substitute this to the Equation 1 you had then you have an equation involving $X$ only

Comment: Multiply both sides by 3.1 in equation 2 and then subtract eq 1 from eq 2

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $-250$, the second with $100$, add both and get $x=116/60=29/15$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}X+Y=10 &\implies 3.1(X+Y)=3.1\times10\\
&\implies 3.1X+3.1Y=31\end{align}$$

This gives two equations where the $X$'s coefficient is the same.
$$\begin{align}
&3.1X+3.1Y=31\\
&3.1X+2.5Y=26.16
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is substitution
\begin{equation}
X+Y=10\text{ and }3.1X+2.5Y=26.16\\
\implies Y=10-X\\
\implies 3.1X+2.5 \big(10-X\big)=26.16\\
(3.1-2.5)X=26.16-25\\
0.6X=1.16\\\quad\implies
X=\frac{1.16}{0.6}=1 \frac{14}{15}\\ 
\implies
Y = 10 - 1 \frac{14}{15}=8 \frac{1}{15} 
\end{equation}

another approach is subtracting identical terms

\begin{align*}
3.1X+2.5Y=26.16\implies 310X+250Y = 2616 \\
X+Y=10       \implies 250X + 250Y = 2500\\
\text{The difference is }\quad 60X = 116\\
\implies X=\frac{29}{15}= 1\frac{14}{15}\\ \\
\
X+Y=10\implies Y= 10-\frac{29}{15}\\
\implies Y=\frac{121}{15}=8 \frac{1}{15}
\\ 
\text{to verify:}\quad 
\\
3.1\bigg(\frac{29}{15}\bigg)+
2.5\bigg(\frac{121}{15}\bigg)\\
= 5\frac{149}{150} + 20\frac{1}{6}\\
=\frac{654}{25 }=26.16
\end{align*}